# Set header directive globally for all virtual hosts in Apache HTTP

Tags: apache-2.2

The header directive says it can be set for the server config context but setting it outside any virtual hosts has no effect. I would like to globally unset a header across all virtual hosts.

I have placed the "Header unset" directive in httpd.conf after setting up a conf.d/header.conf file failed to work. But no luck. I am sure the directive is not being overridden in the hosts config namespace.

thanks

Comment: To ensure that it's working as you expect have you tried putting it in a vhost context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So the header is being set by Drupal in code. I had to add the "always" condition to the Apache directive to get the server setting to override the header.

See the discussion on the "internal table of response headers" in the [Apache docs here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header)

To make it work you need the following in you server config context in the Apache config files:

```
                         Header always unset X-Generator
```

It appears that this was the default in some versions of apache and hence may be the reason that many google results do not mention it.